# Specifying location of install dependancies in mac terminal for PyQt4

Tags: python, macos, installation, cmake, pyqt4

I am trying to install the Eric4 IDE for python on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8. I have downloaded and installed all of the dependencies but when trying to install Eric4 with the command in terminal

```
python install.py
```

And I get this error

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 2.7.3
Sorry, please install PyQt4.
Error: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

I think the problem may be when I use the make command on PyQt4 I get the error

```
make[1]: *** [libpythonplugin.dylib] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I have seen a couple fixes online about this error but none of them seem to work. I have tried to 'clean make' before running the make command and still no luck. How can I install PyQt4 properly so that I can install and run Eric4 IDE?

Comment: Do you use MacPorts? How did you install PyQt4?

Comment: I originally installed it with homebrew and when that did not work I just downloaded it from the PyQt website and ran the make install command.